# How to rename a set of files in the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

How to rename a set of files like this in the Windows command prompt?

current file names:

```
file111.txt  
file112.txt  
file113.txt
```

after renaming file names:

```
file0111.txt  
file0112.txt  
file0113.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: By "DOS" do you mean real MS-DOS, or the Windows "Command Prompt"? The latter is not DOS, but a Windows program with very different features.

Comment: no windows dos i will try your answer

Comment: ...so do you mean Windows **or** DOS? *Windows does not have DOS anymore.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch script:

```
for %%f in (file???.txt) do call :ren %%f
goto :eof

:ren
    set name=%1
    ren "%name%" "%name:~0,4%0%name:~4%"

    :: Here, %name:~0,4% takes the first four characters, then you add a "0",
    :: and %name:~4% is everything after the fourth character.
```

Another possible way, which checks for all files starting with `file100.txt` and so on, so might be slower:

```
for /l %f in (100,1,999) do if exist "file%f.txt" ren "file%f.txt" "file0%f.txt"
```

(If you want to put this in a batch file, you need to change `%f` to `%%f`, same as in the first example.)

Comment: actually i am trying to do this.. rename all files - file.001 to file.1500 as file.0001 to file.1500... could u help?

Comment: @Siva: Use the first method in the answer.

Comment: for %%f in (file.???) do call :ren %%f
goto :eof

:ren
    set name=%1
    ren "%name%" "%name:~0,4%0%name:~4%"

    :: Here, %name:~0,4% takes the first four characters, then you add a "0",
    :: and %name:~4% is everything after the fourth character.  this is not executing.. am i missing something?

Comment: @Siva: 1) I don't understand "this is not executing". Could you give more details? 2) You need to put the entire text in a `*.bat` (or `*.cmd`) file and then run it.

Comment: yes i put in a .bat.. and i changed the file name from file???.txt to file.???

Comment: @grawity: Thanks! it worked, the file names i had starts differently.. that was the issue...